# How to change image preview on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these codes to display the names of the files selected from input and it will preview the FIRST image:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();



    reader.onload = function (e) {

        var filename = input.value;
        var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
        if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
        }
        var files = $('#my_file')[0].files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         $("#files").append('<div class="filename"><span name="fileNameList">'+files[i].name+'</span></div>');

        }

        $("#nextBtn").on("click",function(){

        })
        $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

   }
}
```

What i want to do is that when i click on the "next" button,it will go to the next image selected or if i click on the "prev" button,it will go to the previous image(the last image if im displaying the first one).How do i go about doing this?Thank You.

**UPDATE:**

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("my_file");
$(fileInput).on("change",function(event){
var next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
next.onclick = function(xFlip){
    curImage = curImage+xFlip;
    var files = event.target.files;
    if(curImage > files.length){
        curImage = 1;
    }
    if(curImage == 0){
        curImage = files.length;
    }
    $("#myImg").attr('src',files[curImage-1]);

};
console.log(document.getElementById("myImg").getAttribute("src"));
});
```

I did it this way as the images are retrieved from input type file multiple.
https://jsfiddle.net/bfr6wp7e/2/

Comment: and after update it is still not working?

Please create js fiddle example with html + css + js solution so I can help you more efficiently

Comment: @mkbctrl yeah it is still not working...I have added the js fiddle in my post.Please take a look.Thank you

Comment: @mkbctrl i used method 2 to preview the image but i am not sure how to implement Sridhar's answer there so it is still incomplete. Method 1 is complete but not working..

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I have spare time today, so I will try to make it work for you

Comment: @mkbctrl sorry no..im still not able to solve it

Comment: I have just posted the answer, don't forget to mark it correct if managed to help you ;) Have a nice day mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the challenge, it was my first meeting with the File API :)

[image]

Here is the jsFiddle with what I believe is the correct answer to your question:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrll/aq9Laaew/300936/

JS part

```
const fileInupt = document.getElementById('fileInput')
const fileList = document.getElementById('fileList')

const slickSettings = {
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true
}
const initSlickCarousel = (target, settings) => {
  $(target).slick(settings);
} 

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  console.log('We are handling it sir!')
  const filesArray = Array.from(event.target.files)


  filesArray.map((singleFile) => {
    const outputImg = document.createElement('img')
    const fileReader = new FileReader()

    outputImg.className = 'img-thumbnail'

    // Let's read it as data url - onload won't return a thing without it
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(singleFile)

    fileReader.onload = (event) => { outputImg.src = event.target.result }

    console.log(outputImg)

    fileList.appendChild(outputImg)
  })

 initSlickCarousel(fileList, slickSettings)
}

if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList) { // check if browser can handle this

  console.log('We are good to go sir!')
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', handleInputChange, false)

} else {

  alert('File features are not fully supported. Please consider changing the browser (newest Chrome or Mozilla).')
}
```

Though it won't be possible for me to get a grasp on that tech if not for the following sources:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want!Thank you so much!I will try it out!!

Comment: hi again!Is it possible to add in a function to zoom in/out on the currently displayed picture ONLY?

Comment: everything is possible, I think you can easily google how to do it, especially with Slick.js on board.

Here is the first thing you came across you start googling: https://gist.github.com/GingerBear/62829e6c52218dbb1ad2

Comment: remember that you have by design the funcionality responsive for reading the files separated from the plugin responsive for handling how they are displayed. Maybe instead of Slick.js it would be better to try and use smth like PhotoSwipe?

Comment: and don't forget to mark the answer helpful - it helps other with simillar problem to find the correct solution.
If you will struggle with implementing the Zoom feature, please provide me with a JSfiddle with your current status, I will try to get it from there if I have a spare moment

Comment: Hello could u add in the codes for adding in images aft the slide has been created?Thankiew u have really helped me alot:)

Comment: The `initSlickCarousel(fileList, slickSettings)` does the whole magic here. By default slick.js gets the target wrapper and then all `> firstRow.children` becomes slides. We create children here `fileList.appendChild(outputImg)` by appending them to the list wrapper. Clear enough?

Comment: Lets say i alr opened 2 images.Then i want to add in another image so i open again,the image doesnt add to the slide.it appeared below the slides.. It has an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null"

Comment: I get you. I have updated the code - new URL is available above. If you pick new set of images slick will be reinitialized. 

Please bear in mind that it won't work like if you choose 3 images at first, then click again and select 2 more --> you won't have 5 images in total in the preview. `Attach a file` HTML input flushes all previously selected images if you hit it again, so I adjusted my code accordingly.

If you want such preview, we are talking here about some sort of preloading images and keeping in inside some storage --> local storage ( quiet limited ) in example

Comment: Okay its working now!Thank you so much for your help!!:)

Comment: Hi again.Sorry to trouble u but i have a slight css issue.I wanted my div to resize to the content which is the image so the width and height are set to auto.But becoz of this CSS,the slick will display all the images instead of just one..

Comment: You need to take a look at slick documentation, and slick settings. Also try to google that thing, it's preety common issue. 

Slick have breakpoints, and slides to show variable. It is usually everything I need.

And about the dynamic search... there is a section on it in Slick docs if I recall

Comment: Thank you,i have managed to achieve what i wanted.One last problem,i am unable to zoom on the image,could you help me again with that as i have tried and failed.Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I missed the notification, did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I hope u are free to help as this is quite urgent..thank you..><

Comment: Sorry mate, I am super busy at the moment. please try to work with this solution:
https://codepen.io/hagiang1305/pen/YpXVgO

remember about code order, and apply zoom funcionality once you are sure Slick is initilized

Comment: Its okay.But the zoom in the solution is not really want im trying to achieve.I want it to zoom in like CSS zoom.

Comment: You mean like hover effect? Or same behavior like in the url provided, but with CSS instead of JS

Comment: I mean like when i click on zoom in,it should stay zoomed in instead of moving around

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for Prev and Next image slide.

```
var numImages = 4;
var curImage = 1;

var imgArray =[
  "one.jpg",
  "two.jpg",
  "three.jpg",
  "four.jpg"
];

function imageShow( xflip ) {
 curImage = curImage + xflip;
 if (curImage > numImages)
  { curImage = 1 ; } 
 if (curImage == 0)
 { curImage = numImages ; } 
     document.images[2].src =  imgArray[curImage - 1];
}
```

HTML buttons:

```
<input type="button" value="<< Prev" onclick="imageShow(-1)">
<input type="button" value="Next >>" onclick="imageShow(1)">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i will try it out!!

Comment: ive tried implementing ur method but it did not work.Here is my code.Please take a look again at my post